# Meaning of comments " classdocs" and "constructor"

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have code from another person that I am trying to make sense of. One thing that I have noticed that come up quite often are:

'''
classdocs'''
 (this comes up underneath something like "class Chronometer")

and

'''constructor''' (this comes up in the methods of a class, usually as part of the first methods)

but there is no other qualifying information, and I cannot find anything online related to these, in the context of python. What do these mean?

Answer (score 0):

**Classdocs** = class documentation = text written by the developer explaining how the class works. This is likely a multi-line string (enclosed with triple quotes) with whatever information the dev thought was useful to include. The standard is to put this directly below the line with the class definition, for example:

```
class Foo(Bar):
"""This is my Foo class. It works by
taking the parameters A and B and
doing something with them."""
def method_a(self):
# . . .
```

**Class constructor** = in programming, this is the part of the code that explains how each instance of the class will behave upon "construction", i.e. what attributes and default values my instances have just from being instantiated. In Python, this normally means the `__init__` method, but I've seen people calling a class method that calls `__init__` as a constructor, too.

Comment: So in the case of this code, there is no other documentation/ text within the triple brackets for both "classdocs", and "constructor". My understanding that this is normal for constructor (because that is just explaining that the __init__ method that it is a part of is a constructor), but this is not normal for classdocs because normally this is followed by an explanation of what this text does?